# How to get a run-time type of generic class using roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

For example I have the following type:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T Prop { get; }
}
```

Or let say I have the following method:

```
private static void Method<T>() 
{
     //how I can get a real type of <T>
}
```

How can I get a run-time type of generic class using `roslyn` ? I mean real type of `<T>`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // here I need to get int
    var m = new MyClass<int>();

    // here I need to get object
    var m1 = new MyClass<object>();
}
```

Comment: @Alexander I believe OP is asking about via Rosyln, not at runtime

Comment: If I run it through [roslynquoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/), it shows as `WithTypeArgumentList` (https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4CUf.png) - have you looked for a `TypeArgumentList` or similar under the node? What do you have so far in terms of roslyn code that looks at this?

Comment: @MarcGravell Identifier("T")

Comment: @isxaker are you looking inside the method? or at the call-site? (call-site = `Main`); it is only at the call-site that this is defined

Comment: @MarcGravell yea, you're right. It gets me `Token(SyntaxKind.ObjectKeyword)`

Comment: @isxaker there you go; that's your T

Comment: Just assumes that you didn't want to find usages when this type are using by Reflection. If it's true you can use Roslyn. You should find all usages of your type `MyClass<T>` and analyze what is the `T` currently in usages: it's directly type usages  `MyClass<int>` or is the other type parameter `MyDerived<K> : MyClass<K>` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `MyClass` syntax tree and you want to get the concrete type or instantiated type of `ITypeParameterSymbol T`, the simple answer is, you can't do it with Roslyn.

If you mean how to get the type from instantiation like this `new MyClass<int>()`, the answer is:

```
var genericType = // the ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax from type GenericNameSyntax
var typArg = genericType.TypeArgumentList.Arguments.First();
var type = model.GetSymbolInfo(typeArg).Symbol // this is your concrete type
```

You can also parse the `IdentifierName` or `TypeSyntax` in the `TypeArgument` but it's syntactically, not semantically.

**Update**

Please explain from which point of view you want to get the info about the run-time type.

As I wrote, if you hold the syntax tree of `MyClass<T>` (in your example) you can't get any info. Roslyn can tell you that is a generic type but that it.
The only way to get this info is in run-time (for example, if you in debug mode and you set a breakpoint somewhere in this class and inspect the type of T in the watch window).

If you want to get the type from instanciated syntax like `var m = new MyClass<int>()` in your example, it's easy as I answered.

Comment: I need it via roslyn. I can't do it ? Where is prove ? see @MarcGravell comment

Comment: Roslyn is the compiler, not the runtime. You can do syntactic or semantic (also flow) analysis but you can't know which is T is some class because it can be anyone. If you want to know from where you create the concrete type, sure you can. If for example, you are in debug session in VS you can put the T in watch window and see the concrete type because there you have a concrete T, but not when you have generic T.

Comment: @isxaker I hope I understand what you try to achieve, otherwise, try to explain your question and I help.

Comment: thank. you got it right. i try to get the exact type of T. so analyzing my own code. analyzing all call chains of my method helps me.